# Web Browser execute Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have some code like this:

```
Public Sub runBrowserThread()
        Dim th As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf TestThread)
        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
        th.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TestThread()
        Dim br As WebBrowser = New WebBrowser()
        AddHandler br.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf browser_DocumentCompleted
        AddHandler br.Navigating, AddressOf Me.Navigating
        br.Navigate("http://localhost:55623/test.aspx")
        Application.Run()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Navigating(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs)
        MsgBox("Got here")
    End Sub

    Private Sub browser_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        Dim br = TryCast(sender, WebBrowser)
        br.Document.InvokeScript("LoadAjax")
        If br.Url = e.Url Then
            Console.WriteLine("Natigated to {0}", e.Url)
            ' Stops the thread
            Application.ExitThread()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Test.aspx contains JavaScript code, which is run onload.  However, it is not executed within the webbrowser context.  How do I execute the JavaScript?

Comment: Show the JavaScript please. Also is the script in the header?

Comment: @Zaggler, yes the code is in the header.  What bearing does that have?  I would post the code, but it is about three pages of A4.  Thanks.